# Show progress bar while recording audio

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progress-bar, mediarecorder

I am using `MediaRecorder` to record the audio. And, I want to show a progress bar of that recording process.
My code in recorder template:

```
 <p id="countdowntimer">Current Status: Beginning in<span id="countdown">10</span> seconds</p>
 <progress ref="seekbar" value="0" max="1" id="progressbar"></progress>
```

My function:

```
mounted() {
let timeleft = 10;
const timeToStop = 20000;
const timeToStart = 1000;
const downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
  timeleft -= 1;
  document.getElementById('countdown').textContent = timeleft;
  if (timeleft <= 0) {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById('countdowntimer').textContent = 'Current Status: Recording';


    const that = this;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }, (stream) => {
      that.stream = stream;
      that.audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus',
        audioBitsPerSecond: 96000,
      });

      that.audioRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        that.recordingData.push(event.data);
      };

      that.audioRecorder.onstop = () => {
        const blob = new Blob(that.recordingData, { type: 'audio/ogg' });
        that.dataUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // document.getElementById('audio').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      };

      that.audioRecorder.start();

      console.log('Media recorder started');

      setTimeout(() => {
        that.audioRecorder.stop();
        document.getElementById('countdowntimer').textContent = 'Current Status: Stopped';
        console.log('Stopped');
      }, timeToStop);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
}, timeToStart);
```

}

For Progress bar I'm trying to do:

```
  const progressbar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
  progressbar.value = some value;
```

Here, I need to increase the progress bar according to the recording process .. How to achieve this?

Comment: I have a question about your code: <progress> is a Vue component, not an HTML tag, right? In this case, you should not get it by id which method returns an HTML object but you should get it with this.$refs.seekbar. If progress is a Vue component, you don't have to set its value by progressbar.value but you can pass it as props. If I understood the situation wrong, could you paste als the code of your progress component?

Comment: @MátéWiszt [progress](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp) is and html tag! :)

Comment: @Margon: thank you for the info, I have never used that :) The main point here is how you get the actual progress value. If Shrijana you could save it in a data variable, you can create a watcher for that to always update the value of the progress bar.

Comment: @MátéWiszt I edited the answer to match exactly what shrijana needs to do theorically... by the way don't ever use the progress bar without a good css style, because it's pretty ugly ahah

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<progress ref="seekbar" value="0" max="1" id="progressbar"></progress>
```

do this

```
<progress ref="seekbar" value="0" max="100" id="progressbar"></progress>
```

in your cycle you can calculate your progressbar value as follow:

```
const progressbar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
progressbar.value = 100*(ELAPSED TIME) / timetostop;
```

EDIT:

your "elapsed time" can be calculated as follow

```
elapsedTime = 0;

setTimeout(function () {
   //your functions in the loop:
    elapsedTime+1000;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer! Today I learnt something really new ;)

Comment: @Margon Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain how to calculate and loop in setTimeout function to update the progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem by this way:

```
    const elem = document.getElementById('progressbar');
    let width = 1;
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        const timeTOStopInSec = timeToStop / 1000;
        width += 100 / timeTOStopInSec;
        elem.value = width;
      }
    }, timeToStart);
```